# Encoding MySQL array result in JSON array notation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

```
$markers =array();
$getmap = $mysqli->query("SELECT `desc`,`lat`,`long` FROM map");
$i=0;
$markers = $getmap->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $markers[1]["desc"];
echo $markers;
```

`$markers = json_encode($markers);`

How is it possible such that these will flow properly and it will be read by the JS?
`var position = (markers[i][lat], markers[i][long]);`

Comment: What code? And php or javascript? You should also dump the exact contents of your variables.

Comment: I am able to dump, but the dump will end up in [{datahere},{datahere}] , which is unable to be read by Javascript. My goal is to convert the SQL result in to a Javascript readable format, which is parsing it through a json_encode. But it is unable to be read due to the {}

Comment: You need to post the exact code you are using.

Comment: Updated and seems easier to understand.

Comment: `var markers = <?php echo json_encode($markers); ?>;`. But I don't think the way you are assigning values to `position` is going to work.

Comment: I used to do it this way, `$markers = [
        ['Tampines , Singapore', 1.3468,103.9326],
        ['TP, Singapore', $lat,$long],
    ['Safra, Singapore', 1.344712,103.940217]
 ]` and it works perfectly be referencing each to their position, ie [1][0]. But if I am calling it from the SQL it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way: 
Hopefully it will help:

```
foreach($markers as $i=>$arrMarkes)
{
   $finalArray[$i] =  $arrMarkes; 
}

echo json_encode($finalArray);
```